# React render() doesn't detect output change from function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

So I'm making a protected route with `react-router-dom`. And it works, sort of.

However it only works when I **manually remove token** from localStorage (from the browser' GUI).

Then I'm redirected to */login*, and after successful login I can access my */profile*. However, once token expires, it won't remove token from localStorage and won't return false from `checkAuth()` to `<AuthRoute />` which is inside `render()`. Any tips how to deal with this?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';

import {
  BrowserRouter,
  Route,
  Redirect,
  Switch
} from 'react-router-dom';

import Login from './components/Login';
import Profile from './components/Profile';

const checkAuth = () => {
  const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
  const currentTime = Math.floor(new Date().getTime() / 1000);
  const { exp } = jwt.decode(token);

  if (!token) {
    return false;
  }

  if (exp < currentTime) {
    localStorage.removeItem('token');
    return false;
  }
  return true;
};

const AuthRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => (
  <Route
    {...rest}
    render={props =>
      checkAuth() ? (
        <Component {...props} />
      ) : (
        <Redirect
          to={{
            pathname: '/login',
            state: { from: props.location }
          }}
        />
      )
    }
  />
);

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
          <AuthRoute exact path="/profile" component={Profile} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: AuthRoute would have to re-render for the <Redirect /> to work, so maybe your function checkAuth is working properly, but never being called due to AuthRoute not rerendering

Comment: From my debugging, this is exactly what happens. But I don't know how to solve it as I'm complete beginner in React. Although it doesn't explain why `localStorage.removeItem()` doesn't remove token from the browser.

Comment: Wouldn't that remove the token from the browser, but not trigger a re-render?

Comment: Yeah it doesn't trigger re-render, but it also doesn't remove token once it's detected to be expired.

Comment: it doesn't remove the token, because it's not being called, because nothing triggers re-render.

Comment: Isn't `checkAuth()` triggered every time when page is reloaded?

Answer (score 0):

`checkAuth()` will call on refresh the page and on changing routes. Also make sure your if condition working properly.